# Using 1 row of data to create up to 3 rows of output SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I'm trying to create a query in which there can be up to 3 rows of output from 1 row of input:

Any one of the following is not null (e_date/c_date/o_date) -> Create one record in output

Any 2 of the following is not null (e_date/c_date/o_date) à create 2 records in output

All 3 following date fields are not null (e_date/c_date/o_date)à Create 3 records in output

I've attached a picture below of an example for it. If someone could please help me with the code logic on this it'd be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Show us your best attempt so we can build on it.

Comment: But probably a self join using the conditions you describe is the way to go.

Comment: sounds like a simple union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION` to do this. For example:

```
select cch_id, e_date as event_time, 'e_type' as event_type 
from t where e_date is not null
union
select cch_id, c_date, 'c_type' from t where c_date is not null
union
select cch_id, o_date, 'o_type' from t where o_date is not null
order by cch_id, event_time
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply`:

```
select cch_id, v.event_time, v.event_type 
from t cross apply
     (values ('e_type', e_date),
             ('c_type', c_date),
             ('o_type', o_date)
     ) v(event_type, event_time)             
where v.event_time is not null;
```

You can of course include other columns.

`APPLY` implements functionality known as a *lateral join*.  Unpivoting like this is only one example of what lateral joins can do.  This is a good introduction to this functionality.

Comment: Thank you very much!